# App Store not displaying Screenshots in Search

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've just uploaded my first app and the product page displays successfully but the screenshots don't appear in the search making it difficult for users to find my app.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is the app already installed on your device? It appears, as of iOS 15, the App Store will now hide screenshots of apps already installed when browsing search results.

Tested in iOS 17, and source:
https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/09/ios-15-app-store-search-results/